# Java method with abstract class as parameter that returns instance of the child class

Tags: java, abstract-class

I'm sure this will have been asked before but I can't find it after searching for some time.

I need a function that will do something like the following:

```
public static AbstractClass createClass(Class<AbstractClass> theChildClass, int someVariable){
    AbstractClass theInstance = theChildClass.newInstance(someVariable);
    return theInstance;
}
```

Then on AbstractClass I want to define it like so:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass{

    private int someVariable;

    public AbstractClass(int someVariable){
        this.someVariable = someVariable;
        initOnChild();
    }

    protected abstract void initOnChild();

}
```

Then on the child classes I ideally don't want to define the "public ChildClass(int someVariable){}" method, so they look like this:

```
public class ChildClass extends AbstractClass{

    @Override
    protected void initOnChild(){
        //do some stuff
    }

}
```

The ideal outcome I'm after is being able to call the method like so:

```
ChildClass theInstance = UtilityClass.createClass(ChildClass.class, 1);
```

Is this even possible? Any solutions or advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but there is a solution.

First the problem with calling an overriden method in the constructor:

```
abstract class A {

    A() {
        init();
    }

    protected abstract void init();
}

class B extends A {

    public String x = null;
    public String y;

    @Override
    protected void init() {
        x = "x";
        y = "y";
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    B b = new B();
    System.out.printf("x=%s, y=%s%n", b.x, b.y);
}
```

Would of course give:

```
x=null, y=y
```

- in B() - all fields zeroed
- super() called, A()
- in A() B.init() called
- in B() field initialisations are done

But it is not obvious from reading superficially, and when using fields in the base class, can become less obvious.

Now the solution.

As you have a static factory method, maybe place this method in AbstractClass. Then it can call init after construction.

```
public static <T extends AbstractClass> T create(Class<T> childClass, int param) {
    T instance = childClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
    instance.init(param);
    return instance;
}
```

This executes the default constructor.

Should this still be unsatisfactory, then it just might be that some datastructure does not reside in the correct inheritance level, or should be restructured.

Comment: I don't have the reputation to 'mark as useful' but this is exactly what I was after! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No. Constructors are not inherited (and therefore are not members in JLS-speak). Depending on the situation you may want to apply the strategy pattern, say.

(ObNote: Generally it's considered a bad idea to call overrideable methods from constructors, and reflection is almost always a really bad idea.)

Comment: @user3210941 The strategy pattern whereupon you separate a variable behaviour object from the common state. As pattern popularised by the dated "Gang of Four" book. http://www.amazon.co.uk/Design-patterns-elements-reusable-object-oriented/dp/0201633612